# Carrierwave upload works in rails console but not in spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, carrierwave

I have the following model:

```
class Face < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :face_index, :design, :background
  belongs_to :template
  mount_uploader :background, BackgroundUploader
end
```

The BackgroundUploader:

```
class BackgroundUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

When I launch the rails console I can create a Face and save a background to it:

```
f = Face.create(:face_index => 0)
f.background = File.open("/path/to/image.jpg")
f.save!
```

That all works, but when I try to move it to rspec I'm getting a failure:

```
Failures:

  1) Face A new face 
     Failure/Error: @face.background = File.open(image_path)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `background_will_change!' for #<Face:0x007ff63d9f7410>
```

The spec:

```
describe Face do

  before(:each) do
    image_path = Rails.root.join('spec/support/images', '02.jpg').to_s
    @face = FactoryGirl.create(:face)
    @face.background = File.open(image_path)
    @face.save!
  end

  describe "A new face" do
    it { should belong_to(:template) }
  end

end
```

The factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do    
  factory :face do
    face_index 0
  end
end
```

I've seen that error before when uploader column was missing from the db, but if my migrations are correct for dev they should be correct for test, non? Do I need to require something in the spec to make it work?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doh, the answer was my final paragraph, I forgot to run

```
rake db:test:load
```

A good example of taking a break and coming back to a problem.

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly what I needed to get many broken specs to work too!